# How does Minecraft update process work?

Tags: java, minecraft-modding

When you initially launch Minecraft you open the "launcher", which will check if your client is up to date. If it's not it proceeds to download the latest files & then runs the game.

How does this happen? Is the launcher a separate application, which can execute the main jar file?

Comment: I think you actually want to know how you can implement something like this yourself? You should rephrase your question in that way.

Comment: Yeah that was my intention, I guess I can title it "How can I create a update processes similar to Minecraft"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Game Patching Mac/PC](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37706/game-patching-mac-pc)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if you examine Minecraft under the hood you can see that it's just a separate file that will launch the JAR file afterwards. However, you're probably more interested in implementing an update solution for your game yourself. If that's the case, check out [Sparkle](http://winsparkle.org/).